# Get neo4j response in c#

Tags: c#, neo4j, .net-core, cypher

I'm setting up an API in .net Core for communicate with my Neo4jBDD and I get some issues, I can without problem execute all request i made and create nodes / relationships. 
But I didn't find a way for get simply the response of neo4jBDD :/ I just get the "summary" with some informations "nodes created etc".

So my question is: "How can i get "response" of neo4j directly in my code for return it in the swagger ?" 
[image: graph]

Thanks to you for your time :/

Comment: It appears you are using the rest API. You should probably use the [Neo4j .NET Driver](https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/). Also, what is the problem? I can see that your REST response contains the data you queried in the body. If you insist on using REST though, here are the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/) for how to use it.